# Javascript append multiple buffer to sourceBuffer and play them as a single video

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to concatenate multiple buffers but it didn't work, this is the code i'm using :

```
let socket = io();
let mediaSource = new MediaSource();
let video = document.getElementById("player");
let queue = [];
let sourceBuffer;
video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function() {
    sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"');
    socket.on('broadcast', function (buffer) {
        console.log('new  buffer');
        let uIntArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        if (!sourceBuffer.updating) {
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(uIntArray);
        } else {
            queue.push(uIntArray);
        }
    })
});
```

When the first buffer comes the video start to play but as soon as the second buffer comes through socketIO the video freeze, i don't know how to add the second buffer so when the first one ended it moves to play the second one like it is one video. excuse my poor English

Comment: I've tackled the same problem here: https://github.com/oleg131/mvgen/blob/master/main.js

Answer (score 1):

You have to offset current `SourceBuffer` duration after each append:

```
var duration = 0;

...

(within loop)
sourceBuffer.timestampOffset = duration;
var delta = buffer.duration
duration = duration + delta;
```

Comment: how can i merge your code with mine ? do you mean i need to add `var duration= 0;` at the very top with other variables but i don't know where do i need to add the other code

Comment: you need to run the other code every time you append something to `sourceBuffer`. e.g. after you run `sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(uIntArray);`, should need to update `timestampOffset`: `sourceBuffer.timestampOffset = duration;
var delta = buffer.duration;
duration = duration + delta;`

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with sequential stream, just set `sourceBuffer.mode = "sequence"`, then `timestampOffset` will be increased automatically in the order of added chunks.

See [MDN SourceBuffer mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer/mode).

Answer (score 0):

i do not think you can。  mediaSource can only have one video sourceBuffer and one audio sourceBuffer, if you add two the video will fire a error
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/mse/basics